# Where/how to report Stack Overflow typosquatters / malicious sites?

Tags: discussion, support, copycat-sites

There's a very sketchy site at `stackkoverflow <dot> com` (two Ks) which seems to have highly variant behavior based on each visit.

I had cleared my browser history and went to type in `stackoverflow` manually and mistyped it.  The first time I visited it was a blank screen that said "click to verify you're human".  This seemed strange, but since I had just cleared my browser cache I wondered if it was one of the site's "legitimate" CAPTCHAs (since they do come up sometimes, I've been trained to treat it as normal).

But then it asked me to install an extension ("securybrowse") and I knew something was up.  I wasn't wearing my glasses, but I looked and realized a key had stuck while I was typing.

Revisiting it I don't quite get the same behavior, it does other things--forwarding around and trying to get you to log into Facebook (I didn't stick around to figure out what it was doing exactly.)

It's not technically duplicating content, so reporting methods for that seem not to apply.  If there's legal leverage to do anything about it, it would be more of a trademark violation, or something?  Just being a bad actor in general?

I don't know what kind of clout Stack Overflow would have with registrars or browser safety databases to do something about it, but mentioning it here in case someone more up on effective reporting can do so.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow can do *anything* about it, other than filing an official complaint with its host, GoDaddy, for possible malicious impersonation.

Comment: @rene I don't think the team would have an issue with contacts about these types of site. Even though it's not "content" they're trading on the name.

Comment: I just got redirected to a (Norwegian) website that's selling iPhone XS for roughly $2.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Can you elaborate on reopening this question? Your answer here is oddly similar to that on the dupe target

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth one is about copying Stack Exchange content, one is about using the site name to do nefarious things. If you think it is a dupe, that's fine. We can reclose it. The author edited it and pinged me, so I reopened it

Comment: I'm voting to reclose this, many of these clone services are malicious in some way, using dubious ad strategies that might involve malware/phishing for passwords/etc. In the [list of linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/253906?lq=1) for that dupe target, you can see multiple already discussing possible malicious activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the site is not using content without attribution, it's trading on the Stack Exchange names to do possible nefarious activity. So please report it to the network.

Use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) page.

Click on 'contact us' (yes nested contact us)

[image]

That will take you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2F):

On the drop down list select:

[image]

'Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution'

[image]

They take a while to get back to you, but they review all these.

*And my mouse cursor keeps appearing in my screenshots. Apologies.*

Comment: *"Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution"* Ahah! So reproducing SE *with* attribution is fine

Comment: @HostileFork they will deal with any websites that are using the Stack name to do nefarious thingz

Comment: @NickA actually it probably is given our licencing. Some countries will reproduce it as they don't have access to the site due to firewalls. I'm not sure of the ins and out of it. I had that discussion with a CM some time ago.

Comment: +1 for the freehand circle

Answer (score 6):

If the web site tries to install dubious browser extensions, you can report it to "Google Safe Browsing": https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/

That way, it will end up in a blocklist for most web browsers.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did that as well.  I'm always hopeful that these reporting systems are curated enough to not make it too easy for them to be abused by those attempting to report legitimate sites as a form of hacking.  So hopefully Google isn't just taking the word of any botnet filing reports against a URL.